# Domain registered with Google App for Business point to other ip?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I have registered a domain when I was registering Google App for business.
I'm just wondering if I could let that domain point to my server instead of Google site?

If not, how can I release the domain and register it(the same name) from some other domain name provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can manage your DNS records even if you bought the domain as part of the Google Apps sign up. In case you don't want to host your website on Google App Engine or Google Sites you can access the DNS credentials for your assigned provider (Enom, GoDaddy) at Domains -> Advanced DNS Settings from there you should login to your provider console in order to change the settings.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/54693?hl=en

If you want to transfer to another provider, follow the standard procedure that each provider has, it usually requires so email confirmation back and forth. Also, make sure not to renew your domain automatically in the Google Apps admin console, otherwise you may be billed twice for the domain.

Now that [Google is offering DNS-as-a-service](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/03/announcing-google-cloud-dns.html) in the Cloud Platform I wonder when they will end the partner DNS hosting and manage it themselves from end to end.

Answer (score 1):

You can associate your purchased domain with your App Engine application. Go to the Admin Console and then Application Settings. You will see a `Domain Setup` section. Click on Add Domain and follow the steps. For further details, check out the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain).